# Spring Data JPA - "No property 'findAll' found for type 'Auteur'" Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**this is AuteurRepository interface****

```
package com.example.api.repository;

import java.awt.print.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.api.model.Auteur;

@Repository
public interface AuteurRepository extends CrudRepository<Auteur, Long>{

    public Iterable<Auteur> findByNomContaining(String name, Pageable pageable);

    public Iterable<Auteur> findAll(Pageable pageable);
    


}
```

**this is the method in AuteurService where i used the 2 repository methods**

```
public Iterable<Auteur> getAuteurs(int pageNumber, int pageSize,String name) {
        Pageable pageable = (Pageable) PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize);
        if (name == "") {
            return auteurRepository.findAll(pageable);
        }
        return auteurRepository.findByNomContaining(name, pageable);    
    }
```

**And here is my AuteurController **

```
@GetMapping("/listPagination")
    public Iterable<Auteur> getAuteurs(
            @RequestParam int pageNumber, 
            @RequestParam int pageSize,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "") String name){
        return auteurService.getAuteurs(pageNumber,pageSize,name);
        
    }
```

this the error that i get :

**Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.api.repository.AuteurRepository.findAll(java.awt.print.Pageable); No property 'findAll' found for type 'Auteur'**

please someone tell me what did i do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the code is using [`java.awt.print.Pageable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/print/Pageable.html), not [`org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html).  These classes are completely unrelated: the former is an AWT class which deals with [printers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_(computing)), the latter a Spring Data class which deals with data pagination.

Changing the import statement to `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` instead of `java.awt.print.Pageable` should fix this issue.

```java
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
```

Comment: That works for me, I appreciate your help man !